# Does Hive 2.1.1 version supports renaming of database?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, mapr

I used below syntax :
ALTER DATABASE dbname RENAME TO newdbname;

Which hive version support this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not. Based on this they are not planning to implement this feature

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4847